# Open graph post just link to book

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am new to open graph and what i am trying to do is to post a book quote, but without a url. because let's say i want to post a quote from a book using a url from amazon.The problem is that it requires a page that has those og tags, which amazon doesnt.Is there any way to bypass this?

Something like this, but without the book part. Simply put, is there any way of manually specifying the bookname and the thumbnail, instead of using a url to a page that has all that info in a og tag?

```
      function postBook()
  {
      FB.api(
      'me/books.quotes',
      'post',
      {
        body: document.getElementById("quote").value,
        bookname: document.getElementById("book").value,
        book:"http://samples.ogp.me/344468272304428"
      },
      function(response) {
        alert("Posted !");
      }
    );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieved using **[Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-using-the-object-api/)**.

Here you will create a quote object [using](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/) the Object API.

Hope this helps.